# Why is meteor only returning an empty file?

Tags: meteor

I'm using Meteor.js for a new project.

It was working at first, but now when I run meteor it seems to start fine, but when I go to `localhost:3000` my browser automatically downloads an empty file.

I tried clearing my cache, restarting my computer, reinstalling node and reinstalling meteor.
I also tried running the meteor example apps, and creating a new app no matter which one I get the same result of an empty file being downloaded. At wits end, any ideas?

I'm on OS X lion using Google Chrome.

**Edit:**

So, after messing around some more, I'm able to run the examples in `/usr/local/meteor/examples` if I use `sudo meteor --port <some arbitrary port>`.

When I try that with my app though, it says it's running but I still get nothing.

Headers from `curl`ing localhost on the example apps give:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/html
connection: close
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

While my headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Mon, 11 Jun 2012 00:51:47 GMT
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000
last-modified: Sun, 10 Jun 2012 10:36:37 GMT
etag: "0-1339324597000"
content-type: application/octet-stream
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 0
connection: close
```

**Edit2:**
It looks like I get a proper error page if I explicitly throw an error.
But, if there are no errors then my headers are wrong.

**Edit3:***
Or possibly it's an error with my environment, example apps no longer run and I get
`Unexpected mongo exit code 127. Restarting.`

**Edit4:***
Okay, so the mongo error was unrelated. I've tracked the problem back to gzippo, specifically if I comment out:
`app.use(gzippo.staticGzip(path.join(bundle_dir, 'static_cacheable'), {clientMaxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365}));`

in /usr/local/meteor/app/server/server.js

and then have a CLEAR cache (start a new private session) it works!
if my cache isn't clear, a blank file is still served.

So, the static_cacheable directory isn't created which is why gzippo prompts a empty download.

I'm not sure whether this should be patched in meteor's server.js or bundler.js ... going to file a bug

Comment: "It was working at first, but now"...

What changed?

I've found that if there is a JavaScript parsing error, or Handlebars error, then you often get an empty page.

Have you ran meteor update from the command line?
Have you installed any packages you need? (i.e. meteor add handlebars)

Comment: BTW, on browsers, I have had good luck with Firefox with Firebug.  It is very good for diagnosing errors.

Comment: I'm using google chrome;
I worked on a separate project for a bit, and then pulled in my partner's changes. The odd thing is, it still worked for him (he's using archlinux btw) while I was getting nothing.

Comment: @ibash: Weird, don't you notice anything in the changes you pulled? Also, check the JS console in Google Chrome for any JS errors.

Comment: Try following 
1. Change browser to Firefox/firebug
2. Create a new meteor project and try to run default sample code.

Comment: Found where the problem is but needs further investigation, will update question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Filed an issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/177
and made a fix: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/179

It's a problem where a folder (static-cacheable) gzippo expects is not created by meteor.
relevant files in meteor: app/server/server.js:61, app/lib/bundler.js:526

Comment: Answered your own question, filed issue, AND made a fix. Wow. Nicely done. +1